# Change react-bootstrap container width

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

How do I change the default with of container in bootstrap to something smaller?

I would like it to be a bit smaller in terms of total width. Is there a way to do this so that it works on all viewports? relatively shorter than what the width already is?

Answer (score 0):

While you could override the CSS of container, another option would be using the column layout instead to wrap your content.

Something like this:

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';

function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col sm={3}></Col>
        <Col sm={6}>

            PLACE CONTENT HERE

        </Col>
        <Col sm={3}></Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}
```